# backbone.js and handling errors messages from rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, backbone.js

I wonder if backbone.js users could please help me?

What is the best way to encode error messages from a rails app when used with backbone.js for example those error messages that were once defined as flash messages eg "record not found".

Most of the time errors can be defined in the client, however, sometimes you want to pass a error that you have defined in the server side code, which means the result from the server is different than expected from normally receiving a list of records into a collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set your rails controller as:

respond_to :json

You will receive your errors as json (you need to use respond_with(object) )

```
class XYZController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json
  responders :jsons
  def create
    @xyz = Xyz.new( params[:xyz] )
    @xyz.save
    respond_with @xyz, :location=>@xyz.id.nil? ? "" : edit_xyz_url(@xyz)
  end
end
```

I created my json responder to better deal with backbone:

```
module Responders

  module JsonResponder 

    def to_json
      raise error unless resourceful?

      if get?
        display resource
      elsif has_errors?
        display resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity
      elsif post?
        display resource, :status => :created, :location => api_location
      elsif put?
        display resource, :status=>:ok, :location => api_location
      elsif has_empty_resource_definition?
        display empty_resource, :status => :ok
      else
        head :ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @Julien  how do you handle that response in your example in backbone.js? I am interested to see.

Comment: is this using the responders gem?

Comment: yes, please expand a little on how you're handling this in Backbone - I think it would be helpful

Comment: Not sure I get your question here. This is RoR code to make it behave correctly for backbone. On the client side, there is nothing to do.

Comment: well presumably some sort of DRY strategy for appending error messages to forms, reverting changes to the ui on server errors etc. Do you override backbone.sync to handle this stuff?

Comment: I do not override sync for that. Errors will come in the "error" callback on the save in the model (you'll have to handle this). My UI is different at many places so handling the errors is kind of different from places to places and depends on the layout of your form/view. So if you come up with something to DRY things up, be my guest on post it somewhere.